# issue with fallback javascript it only loads the internal not external

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey so i'm trying to add fallback javascripts. External source should be default on loading but when it fails on loading then the data from local js will take place.When i tried using two different methods below in sample codes it only loads the local script only but not the external. Any help will be appreciated.

CODES

```
<script src="//external.com/name.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="local/name.js">\x3C/script>')</script>

<script>
    if (typeof $.tooltip === 'undefined') {
        document.write('<script src="local/name.js">\x3C/script>');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So maybe `//external.com/name.js` is wrong path. But sounds like you don't load tooltip plugin and so `typeof $.tooltip === 'undefined'` returns true. Then comes the questions, what is supposed to load: `//external.com/name.js`??? How do you debug it? Etc...

Comment: the path is correct i have it in correct url format as in http://external.com/name.js okay so answer to your question when loading from external it will show the actual data but when loading the data from local if the script fails the it will show like "loading error" for the data.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Your code supposes `//external.com/name.js` will include jQuery library and a jquery tooltip plugin (maybe jQuery UI one, and then, it should include jQuery UI too), both at once. I don't think it is what it is doing. Otherwise, i don't understand why you are checking for `window.jQuery` and `$.tooltip`???

Comment: im not using jquery i'm using my own personal javascripts  this is the code i found through my research which is suppose to do what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Ok but no, this isn't what it is suppose to do. If you aren't using jQuery, there is no meaning of checking for it, and btw using jQuery tag in question. So instead of this XY problem, explain what is your expected behaviour. Checking if external script failed to load?

Comment: i have external javascript which has all of the updated data if that javascript fails then then the local will take place and it will give errors on the data saying "Failed to loading data" i hope that helps.

Comment: the local data has same data as external but except for the actual data it has "fail to load data" error the real difference between both of the scripts

Comment: It sounds like you just want to use `onerror` script event but i'm really not sure to understand what you mean. Your best bet would be to provide sample as a jsfiddle replicating your issue

Comment: just made an fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w2ebgkrw/

Comment: scripts set this way are loaded synchronously so your jsFiddle cannot work. Maybe what you want is too handle script error: http://jsfiddle.net/w2ebgkrw/1/  and here when external script failed to load: http://jsfiddle.net/w2ebgkrw/2/

Comment: for onerror can i use local path? like /local/script.js

Comment: sure just set the handler, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/w2ebgkrw/4/  Now if your extrenal script set a global variable, you could check for it instead and then you will get the same logic as your posted code in question, replacing `window.jQuery` with `window.myGlobalVariable`